# Handling Concurrent Servlet Requests on Domino Server

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

I am trying to create a REST service using a Servlet that lives inside an NSF. The Servlet runs but I noticed that it handles requests one at a time, so if a request is waiting for a database query to finish, all other requests must wait. I know that requests for Servlets on Tomcat or Glassfish get their own thread but that doesn't seem to be happening on the Domino server.
To try and get around this I tried to spawn new threads inside the Servlet but kept getting NotesContext not initialized errors. I searched around and found a project called [Threads and Jobs](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Threads%20and%20Jobs), and intended to use the code there to create a Servlet that spawns new threads and gives the client a requestId and requires them to poll to retrieve the job results, or listen on a port that the server will broadcast on when finished. When I tried to import the project and run it as is, the pages Thread.xsp and Job.xsp rendered but weren't functional. I get the following output in the console:

Thread started

>> Thread running

java.lang.NullPointerException

> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getRunningModule(NotesContext.java:394)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.checkSignerRightsNonXSP(NotesContext.java:960)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ModuleClassLoader$DynamicClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:379)
> >
> > at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:626)
> >
> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread$1.run(ThreadSample.java:86)
> >
> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread$1.run(ThreadSample.java:1)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor$3.run(ThreadSessionExecutor.java:156)
> >
> > at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor.run(ThreadSessionExecutor.java:154)
> >
> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread.run(ThreadSample.java:123)

>> Thread running

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: lotus/domino/Session

> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread$1.run(ThreadSample.java:86)
> >
> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread$1.run(ThreadSample.java:1)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor$3.run(ThreadSessionExecutor.java:156)
> >
> > at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
> >
> > at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.ThreadSessionExecutor.run(ThreadSessionExecutor.java:154)
> >
> > at org.openntf.samples.thread.ThreadSample$MyThread.run(ThreadSample.java:123)

>> Thread stopping

Thread left

Answer (score 1):

You need to design the servlet as OSGi plug-in otherwise it doesn't find the Domino classes. Check [this sample](http://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development) for code samples, also have a look at [my code](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-99U64Q) for threads and check out [Serdar's project](http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XTasks) on OpenNTF/GitHub

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: ummm... Serdar... ummm... :)

Comment: @SerdarBasegmez Typos happen when you peck on glass - sorry for that. Fixed it

Comment: When using your code for threads I get the error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: NotesContext not initialized for the thread

Comment: The code depends on the Extlib. You have that one? I also tested on R9 only. Amend your question and show your code